# Recieved emails not read in the program during the reconnection session using EWS Streaming Notification

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Everything is okay, I can now receive emails real-time using streaming notification but what happens after the 30-minute limit? It reconnects but this process may take some time (seconds?), but what if an email happens to come before it even connects again to the StreamingSubscriptionConnection? I haven't tried this yet but how should this be solved if ever? Is there any way to retrieve the unread emails (inside the streaming notification) during the said session?

My code under disconnect is just this:

```
streamingConnection.Open();
```

I'm not good with explaining so let me know if my question is too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with your first question: The reconnection process takes milliseconds not seconds. As far as what happens if you get an email during this VERY short period  of time two things. 
1. It is very unlikely.
2. If it EVER happens, streaming notifications have a few second delay in other words the notification is received 1-4 seconds after the actual event to be precise which means you will still get it. It's ok to be left with so many questions given that the documentation is almost non-exiatent I had the same questions while developing my exchange windows service, so feel free to ask me any questions I'm glad to help.

The 3rd question im having trouble understanding can you be a bit more specific? I know streaming notifications will alert you if an email has been read or not via messageType.isRead property.

I think what you need is look into the synchronization functionality that exchange provides. It is very important that you somehow keep track or "backups" of your mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for this! I did look for synchronization functionality but still confuse on how to implement it on my program. But since it only takes few milliseconds to reconnect, I don't think I'll add that anymore. Anyways, what I would like to accomplish there is sync it then retrieve those emails that aren't read during the reconnection session. When I say read, the contents of the email will be stored in the database.

Comment: Well dont worry about the reconnect process too much id be more concerned about the ondisconnect event. What would you do if you lose internet connectivity or the exchange server goes down you know?

Comment: Hi! I finally tried running the program for 30 minutes but I got this error: The specified subscription was not found. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: That usually happens when the Subscription was either manually removed or it was not re opened on time that it timed out, can you post your code?